# Angular router-ui views are rendered before JS Scripts

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to create a Single page application with multiple views (header, footer, sidebar, mainPage ...) every view has some animations on it (js scripts), first all componenats were attached to index.js, but after using Router-ui and separating views, i found that animations are not working anymore (jquery, bootstrap.js ...)

here is the scripts in the index.html:

```
<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Modernizr -->
<script src='js/modernizr.min.js'></script>

<!-- Pace -->
<script src='js/pace.min.js'></script>

<!-- Popup Overlay -->
<script src='js/jquery.popupoverlay.min.js'></script>

<!-- Slimscroll -->
<script src='js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js'></script>

<!-- Cookie -->
<script src='js/jquery.cookie.min.js'></script>
```

and here is an example of a views :

```
$stateProvider
  .state('main', {
    abstract: true,
    views: {
      'header': {
        templateUrl: 'components/partials/header.html'
      },
      'sidebar': {
        templateUrl: 'components/partials/sidebar.html'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('chat', {
    url: '/chat',
    parent: 'main'
      views: {
        'main@': {
          templateUrl: 'components/chat/chat.html',
          controller: 'ChatController',
          controllerAs: 'chatCtrl'
        }
      }
  });
```

there is a way to tell angular to wait until all scripts are loaded? or maybe a library to facilitate my task, if yes please give an example, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the ng-cloak directive to your uiview container should make angular wait until the content is finished loading before displaying.

```
<div ui-view ng-cloak></div>
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak for additional information.

P.S. Sorry I can't comment yet

Comment: Try putting the ng-cloak to the body element

Comment: No, still nothing, i think it has something to do with ocLazyLoad, requirejs (i don't see how to us them with angular)... because when i use index.html with all componenants (header, sidebar, footer) animations (made by js) are working, but when integrating ui-views and separating (header, footer .. etc) from index, HTML is rendered but animations are not working, Thanks Max